# Можно ли с помощью python и bs4 спарсить элемент tr в таблице, если у него нету класса, айди и других атрибутов?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Код пока что выглядит следующим образом, но выдаёт пустой словарь:

```
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tr_list = soup.find_all('tr')
    items = []
    for tr in tr_list:
        items.append({
            'attribute': item.find('td', class_='drawRowBorder').get_text(strip=True)
        })
    print(items)
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: Какой сайт? Вы сначала проверьте, что у вас в `html`. Сайт может быть построен целиком на `JavaScript` и тогда без `Selenium` вы его содержимое нормально не увидите. А если сайт обычный, то, возможно, проще парсить данные из таблиц с помощью `Pandas`.

Comment: скиньте ссылку на сайт который парсите, иначе вам вряд ли смогут помочь

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin сайт: https://boxrec.com/en/ratings нужно спарсить таблицу с участниками

Answer (score 1):

Ну например можно так получить таблицу в датафрейм

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import pandas as pd
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response_gippo = requests.get('https://boxrec.com/en/ratings',headers=headers)
soup = Soup(response_gippo.content, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find('tbody')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

Comment: на строчку table_rows = table.find_all('tr') выдает 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
может ли проблема быть в интерпретаторе?

Comment: @MaybeNick у меня этот код отрабатывает без проблем. python 3.9.4, запускаю через cmd

Comment: возможно мне стоит использовать Selenium?